# Chart helper in ASP.Net Display DateTime

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, charts

In a asp.net mvc application, I need to create a simple line-chart, so I tried Chart helper. The chart is created using two list, the x-axis should display datetimes, and the y-axis should display a value for each time. Now this works fine using the code below. "listOfDateTimes" consists a list of DateTimes.

```
    var chart = new Chart(width: 1000, height: 300, theme: ChartTheme.Green)
        .AddSeries(
                    chartType: "line",
                    xValue: listOfDateTimes,
                    yValues:  listOfValues )
                    .GetBytes("png");
```

The problem is that the datetimes below the x-axis shows up as "MM/dd/yyyy", but I also need to display the hour and minutes. I can't figure out how to solve this using Chart helper.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When using Chart Helper you have to customize your chart by providing your own theme file:

```
 var myChart = new Chart(width: 800, height: 400, themePath: "MyTheme3.xml")
              .AddSeries(
                          chartType: "line",
                          xValue: new[] { DateTime.Now,
                              DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(1),
                              DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(2),
                              DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(3),
                              DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(4) },
                          yValues: new[] { 40, 100, 60, 80, 20 })
```

Use this sample theme to customize your X-axis as described:

**MyTheme3.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Chart>
  <ChartAreas>
    <ChartArea Name="Default">
      <AxisX>
        <LabelStyle Format="MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss"></LabelStyle>
      </AxisX>
    </ChartArea>
  </ChartAreas>
  <Series>
    <Series Name="Default"></Series>
  </Series>
</Chart>
```

[image]

---

**EDIT:** If you want to configure your chart the regular way through properties, then you should use `System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting` namespace. But if you want to use `System.Web.Helpers` namespace then you have to do it like explained before.

Comment: Thank you! That fixed my problem. 
For future visitors: Here is some examples that gives you a hint of what you can customize on your xml.
https://dzone.com/articles/chart-helper-aspnet-mvc-3